# How to assign value on-click live search

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I have the below code working perfect but I will like if anyone can help me with onclick of the search result to get the ID of the searched item and open in another page by parsing the ID of the item to the URL. GET preferably.

**backend-search.php**

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","","","");
 
// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
 
if(isset($_REQUEST["term"])){
    // Prepare a select statement
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM countries WHERE country_name LIKE ?";
    
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_term);
        
        // Set parameters
        $param_term = $_REQUEST["term"] . '%';
        
        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            
            // Check number of rows in the result set
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                // Fetch result rows as an associative array
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                    echo "<p>" . $row["country_name"] . "</p>";
      echo "<p>" . $row["id"] . "</p>";
              

                }
            } else{
                echo "<p>Not found</p>";
            }
        } else{
            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
        }
    }
     
    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
 
// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Above is the code that queries the database to fetch the array list of values to display on the search result and it ID to search.php. Find below the index page for the live search:

**index.php**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function() {
    /* Get input value on change */
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
    if (inputVal.length) {
      $.get("backend-search.php", {
        term: inputVal
      }).done(function(data) {
        // Display the returned data in browser
        resultDropdown.html(data);
      });
    } else {
      resultDropdown.empty();
    }
  });

  // Set search input value on click of result item
  $(document).on("click", ".result p", function() {



    $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());

    $(this).parent(".result").empty();


  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arail, sans-serif;
}


/* Formatting search box */

.search-box {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.search-box input[type="text"] {
  height: 32px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.result {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.search-box input[type="text"],
.result {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Formatting result items */

.result p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-top: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.result p:hover {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-box">
  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search country..." />
  <div class="result"></div>
</div>
```

The above has the ajax code that calls the backend-search.php and it has the input field for the search filter. The

```
<div class"result"></div>
```

is the dropdown for the search filter result. What I want is on click on the

```
<div class"result"></div>
```

it should redirect user to another page with ID of the item selected. For example "new-page.php?id=2".

Kindly find below a screenshot of the output
[image]

Comment: Please show a rendered example of the php output

Comment: @mplungjan kindly find update with output of search result.

Comment: Rendered as in view source html